# Are BrowserStack devices Rooted or Jail broken?

Tags: android, ios, jailbreak, browserstack, rooted-device

So i've been trying to check if BrowserStack devices are rooted or jailbroken because i have a need to test whether my application should be usable on a rooted or Jail broken devices.This is due to security concerns i will be preventing users from using the app if Rooted/Jail broken.

Comment: Contact their support and ask them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because customer support questions are off-topic

Comment: I contacted support and they said that they don't have rooted devices, AND they were wrong because some of the devices were rooted.And i think this question and comment would help a lot of developers.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, BrowserStack doesn't offer support for rooted devices.